# How to find the port (/dev/smdX) to which the AT commands should be sent?

Tags: linux, embedded, adb, at-command, qualcomm

I've been using the following format for sending AT commands from the Application processor (AP) to the modem subsystem:

```
cat /dev/smd7 &
echo -e "ati\r" > /dev/smd7
```

It has always worked but I never realized where's `/dev/smd7` port coming from. After looking up online, looks like it's referring to the port used by Radio Interface Layer (RIL), but how does one confirm it?

I have lately started getting timeout issues and I'm starting to wonder if the port may be incorrect or might have changed

```
read error: Network dropped connection on reset
```

Note that AP is running linux

**Edit:**
Looks like the modem keeps rebooting hence the read error. But it seems to happen after running the two commands above

Comment: I admit I don't know the answer of it is even possible. But maybe, if the device is connected through a USB port, you could listen on every new device event, triggering your program to acquire the dev name if it matches a specific vid&pid couple.

Comment: in debug uart logs, the relevant dev I am seeing is `/dev/ttyMSM0`, and I don't see `/dev/smd7`

Comment: Does `/dev/smd` feature in `dmesg`'s output?  `dmesg | grep '/dev/smd/` ... if the problem were on the device driver level I'd expect it not connect at all rather than intermittently.

Comment: no. `dmesg | grep smd7` doesn't really output anything